# How to map mutlitple <td> tag in a <tr> tag using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have to map multiple `<td>` data in a single `<tr>` using regex in python

for example

```
<tr>
  <td>data 1</td>
  <td>data 2</td>
  <td>data 3</td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract data1,data2, data3 using a single regular expression. And there can be any number of `<td>` tags.

Currently I'm using multiple regex ie first I'm mapping `<tr></tr>` and then `<td></td>`

Can I do it in single expression?

I want to achieve this using regex, so I can't use beautiful soup or other html parsers.

Comment: you should parse html with html parser and not with regex

Comment: as long as you can guarantee no nested tags you are probably alright...but regex _CANNOT_ match nested items correctly...

Comment: *"I want to achieve this using regex, so I can't use beautiful soup or other html parsers."*. Sorry, but that's a bit like asking for help stabbing out your eyes with a fork. You generally do not want to do that, because it's not a good idea! Do you have any more compelling reasons to not want to use a HTML parser?

Comment: "i want to achieve this using regex , so i can't use beautiful soup or other html parsers." Why is using a regex so important for you? You **really** shouldn't do it. Please read *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1248554)*!

Comment: While @zenpoy is *absolutely* right, this question isn't actually a duplicate. The "close for exact duplicate" selection shouldn't be used just for linking to a question/answer that the OP should read.

Answer (score 3):

Although, as others have suggested, you should be parsing your HTML with something designed for the task, the following will work for a subset of cases:

```
re.findall(r'(?i)<td.*?>([^<]+)</td.*?>', input_str)
```

Depending on the format of your HTML input, you may need to convert it to a string before working with `re.findall()`. The following will read from `file.html` and store any matches in a list called `data`:

```
import re

fh = open('file.html', 'r')
input_str = fh.read()
data = re.findall(r'(?i)<td.*?>([^<]+)</td.*?>', input_str)
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I get it, The Pony, He Comes. I too spread the word every now and then, as I absolutely agree with the view. But that view seemed more than sufficiently expressed in the comments above, so I aimed simply to **answer the literal question**, "Can I do it in [a] single expression?"  With a simple: "No, except in .NET, so move along."

---

To answer your actual question:

No, you cannot do it in a single expression, unless you're using .NET, which, so I've heard, provides captures for each instance matched within a quantified expression.

The best you can do is a finite, non-arbitrary repetition, e.g.

```
 /<tr>(?:\s*<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:\s*<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:\s*<td>(.*?)</td>)?(?:\s*<td>(.*?)</td>)?\s*</tr>/
```

Of course, the above is crude and doesn't take into account any other tags, comments, etc.  I only mean to exemplify the "finite, non-arbitrary" part.